# Elemento fora do dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para exibir uma ul/div que esta dentro do dialog?
Observe no canto inferior direito do dialog

```
<div id="dialog">
        <div>  <div>    <button id="status-candidato">Run last action</button>  <button id="select">Select an action</button>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Open...</li>
        <li>Save</li>
        <li>Delete</li>        
      </ul></div>

    </div>


<script>
 $('#dialog').dialog({
            title:"Titulo",
            width:800,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: "top"

...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONSEGUI!!

```
#dialog {  overflow: visible; }
.ui-dialog { overflow: visible; }
```

tem que forçar a class do dialog a exibir

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que da pra consertar isso com o `z-index`:

```
#dialog {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: não da já tentei diversas formas com css (word-wrap,display, z-index, overflow), parece que o dialog delimita a div